Sumara Valores a la derecha de un Datagridview
Tengo un grid que despues de procesarlo lo mando a un csv
en resumen tengo esta tabla que semanaN pueden variar y solo debo sumar semanaN ,
ya logre hacer la suma de los valores hacia abajo pero no puedo hacer la suma hacia la derecha, ya esta contemplado la suma de los textos y los omiti
Asi Seria el reultado final de "suma"

For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns

         StrExport &= c.HeaderText & ","
     Next
     StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
     StrExport &= "100% GRAVADAS," & Environment.NewLine
     For Each filaDato As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

         For Each dc As DataGridViewCell In filaDato.Cells
             StrExport &= Replace(If(dc.Value Is DBNull.Value, 0, dc.Value), ",", " ") & ","
         Next



         StrExport = StrExport.Substring(0, StrExport.Length)
         StrExport &= Environment.NewLine
     Next

     StrExport &= Replace("", ",", " ") & ","
     StrExport &= Replace("", ",", " ") & ","
     StrExport &= Replace("", ",", " ") & ","

     Try
         For i = 3 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
             Dim sum_total As String = "0"
             For Each dw1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                 sum_total += dw1.Cells(i).Value
             Next
             StrExport &= Replace(sum_total.ToString, ",", " ") & ","

         Next
     Catch ex As Exception
         StrExport &= Replace("0", ",", " ") & ","
     End Try```





Que es dc ?? Yo creo que no estás entendiendo que quieres hacer en el código.

Acabo de explicar un poco mejor mi problema , gracias

No entiendo tu problema.. o sea.. estas generando la linea que vas a exportar vos.. porque en el momento que generas la linea no sumas las columnas que queres y agregas al final ese valor?
